# Is there any cross-platform command-line library for C++?

Tags: c++

To run a command line using C++, I always use `system` command. However, I think this way is too error-prone since I only can parse a `char*` as argument without any other information. So I'm looking for a cross-platform library that works well with command-line? Has anyone known one?

Thanks,
Chan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Boost.Process](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/). It is still work in progress and is not part of the official Boost yet, but looks promising.

Comment: I really did not know Boost has this great library. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

QProcess from Qt does this in a cross-platform manner.

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qprocess.html

From the documentation above, the example usage is:

```
// some parent object
QObject * parent;

QString program = "./path/to/Qt/examples/widgets/analogclock";
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "-style" << "motif";

QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(parent);
myProcess->start(program, arguments);
```